# How to increase number of enemies in arraylist with each level?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm making a game where each level the number of enemies increases by one. After the 10th level, there would be a boss fight. 
my code I have now is:

```
public void newLevel() {
    if (mAsteroidList.isEmpty()) {
        mAsteroidCreateTimer++;
        if (mAsteroidCreateTimer >= 50) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                mAsteroidList.add(new ZeAsteroids(mShip.mXPos, mShip.mYPos));
```

adds news enemies around my ship coordinates

```
            }
            mAsteroidCreateTimer = 0;
        }
    }
```

What I want is for each level be previous level + 1. First level would have 6 enemies, and so on all the way to 14 (level nine).

Comment: when `mAsteroidCreateTimer` reached 51 you will create 6 enemies(?`ZeAsteroids`). I assume that `mAsteroidList.isEmpty()` is false after this has happened. so `newLevel` will do nothing when `mAsteroidCreateTimer` has reached 51 the first time (after the 51 call to `newLevel`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a private int variable to store the number of enemies in the level, use that instead of 6 ,then when you advance a level increment the variable.